# How to view the source of currently displayed html page(dynamically) than the original page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, greasemonkey, stylish

G'day everybody,
            As an avid firefox user, I use plugins like stylish and Greasemonkey to modify default styles of pages. However the view->page source option of the browser shows only the page in its original form and not the current form after it is manipulated by a script or a style. Is there any way i can view the source of a page based on what is displayed on the browser and not the original page sent by the server?.
Any suggestions would be much be appreciated.
Thanks.

paul bullard

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com)...

Firebug allows you to inspect the current DOM, CSS and loaded JavaScripts on the fly.

You can also modify anything on the current document and see the results automatically.

Comment: It is indispensable (especially when modifying the Stack Overflow Layout with Greasemonkey).

Comment: Thanks. Nice Extension. It seems firebug doesn't have any quick way to save the current html page(had to do Edit->Ctrl+A Ctrl+C and then open an editor and Ctrl+V followed by Ctrl+S). Is there any way to quickly save the source of the displayed page. Thanks again for your suggestion. :)

Comment: Just right-click the `<html>` tag and select *Copy HTML*...

Answer (score 0):

Firebug is option for the Mozilla FireFox. There is [IE developer tool-bar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359) for IE users.
Almost all browser now a days come with the view source tool or plugin.

Chrome has its debugging tool you can use Firebug for IE, chrome, FIrefox it has provided plugin for all these popular browsers. Please refer its [site](http://getfirebug.com/)