# How can I see the coded results of a $('#x').html(.....) call?

Tags: html, debugging, browser

The browser renders my changes properly for that function, but I cannot see the source when I use the 
"view source" menu item. How can I see the changed source HTML?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Way to View Generated Source of Webpage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750865/best-way-to-view-generated-source-of-webpage)

Answer (score 3):

This is browser-specific, but a debugging console (Firebug, etc.) will do this.

Comment: I'm not actually sure you can, at least with Firebug. Firebug, indeed, shows the DOM tree, and that *does* change with page changes, but the source is what was initially called into the page, and that is static.

Comment: I see what you mean, and you're correct as far as viewing raw source goes.

Answer (score 2):

"View generated source" in the *Web Developer Toolbar* for Firefox will open a view-source like view of the *current* page source.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern browsers have debuggers and dev tools available as addons or built-in.

Chrome and IE8 has it built-in although it's not in the right-click context menu on IE8 and is instead in 'Tools' or you can hit F12.
On Firefox you can install Firebug.

Usually what you're looking for isn't available through 'view source' but instead use 'Inspect Element'.

You'll probably find a lot of your debugging work is done in the script debugger and exploring in the DOM.

Comment: True, it's not 'hidden' I guess, but a little elusive if you're used to Firefox/Chrome where it's in the right-click context menu.  I've edited to clarify that.