# How to compare 2 Websites after changes in Backend / Framework

Tags: php, unit-testing

Following "problem":

Website build with PHP/HTML working
We want to change this site to PHP + Zend Framework + HTML

The Goal: After implementing the Framework the site should look like without the Framework.

Is there any way to test this automaticly? If we just save the page before and compare it with the new version i will not work because some Whitespaces inside the html sourecode can be different.

Is there any working solution for this scenario?

Comment: You can using a comparison tool that ignores whitespace. I think WinMerge and Beyond Compare can both do that (I use the latter).

Comment: Beyond Compare most definitly can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it looks like you want to compare two html pages to see if they are same.

Try this : minify the html of both pages. i think it will solve the extra empty spaces problems and then generate md5 hash or compare them or some other way you like .

Or use generated source of both of the pages can use firebug or some other tool like fiddler its already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750865/best-way-to-view-generated-source-of-webpage) on how to get generated source.

Comment: The idea to minify the pages is excelent! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Backup all files and test Zend with duplicate files.

Comment: Copy the folder for your project and paste it. Call it project-backup. Modify the project files to use Zend.

Comment: i've to verify that the browser output looks the same after refactoring (talking about 50 Forms, and a lot more content pages)

Comment: So your real question is how to automate the process of viewing 50 webpages. Use Selenium.

Comment: not realy, you can test with selenium if an <h1> is available but not if it fits in the page perfetct.