# View Page Source in Browser does not shows the correct gridview data

Tags: gridview, view

I have a gridview for which JQuery drag and drop method is used to rearrage the rows. When I used the "View Page Source" option to see how the HTML part would look , I can see the gridview rows arranged in HTML table format (like Table, TR and TD ) and in the same order as the displayed data. But even if I rearranged the rows from client side (using the drag option implemented for the gridview), the order of  elements remain the same when checked with the "View Page Source" .

So my question is whether the displayed content has direct relation with the "Page SOurce" of browser or is it shows only the Source of the content loaded during the page load process?

Can any one clarify this?

Example::
Gridview contains 
A
B
C
D

Source  elements are also in the same order.
If rearranged rows from client side as B,C,A,D the Page source  order remains the same

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Way to View Generated Source of Webpage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750865/best-way-to-view-generated-source-of-webpage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the question below that has a lot of information about this...

Basically the browser tries to give the version of the page, but the generation of that source code is different from what you get to see in the browser window.

[Generate source of webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750865/best-way-to-view-generated-source-of-webpage)

They also suggest some techniques to get the one you want (see DOM page javascript suggestion)

Comment: I am not looking for any tool as in the answer above, but how a page is related with the "View Page Source" HTML content, and also if I make any change in the browser page, does it will affect the "View Source" HTML part as well?

Comment: It seems that not everything you see on the page, is also reflected in the model in memory of the browser. So when you ask the page source, you only get the model from memory and not how it looks for real.

Comment: ok.. so we cannot say that the page source exactly represents the view of the page in HTML form.