# Need insight on why BeautifulSoup unable to query elements with class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For this simple BeautifulSoup experiment, I am trying to scrape some simple data from an IMDB page `https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7069210/`

The problem is **I am unable to get the elements with class `rec_item`**. I have tried many selectors to get the hold of it, but each time it is giving back a blank list.

Now, why I think it is strange is:

- The elements with `rec_item` are not inside any iFrame.
- The elements can be seen by doing `view page source` on browser. Therefore, as per my understanding, they are *NOT* loaded by javascript after page load.

Here is the [repl.it link of the code](https://replit.com/@SumanBarick/movie-hunter#main.py)

**Question:** Can anyone please help me understand why the list of `rec_item` is blank?

**Additional Information**

Here is the code,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def extract(url):
    res = requests.get(url)
    bsoup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    the_title = bsoup.select('meta[name="title"]')[0].attrs['content']
    print('Title: ' + the_title)    # This works fine

    long_text = bsoup.select('#titleStoryLine .inline.canwrap span')[0].string.strip()
    print('Description: ' + long_text)    # this too works fine

    similar_movies = bsoup.select('.rec_item')
    print(similar_movies)   # blank array :(


extract('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7069210/')
```

Browser's View Page Source
[image: Browser's View Page Source]

And here is the output from repl.it
[image: Code output from repl]

Comment: Recommendations are dynamically loaded with js (they are not in the body you download). You can't do it with requests, try it with selenium.

Comment: @Lucas But they are available in "view page source" and that's what making it mysterious to me. As this SO link's (below) accepted answer says: "View Source in the browser shows you the original HTML source of the page - exactly what came from the server before any client side modifications have been made.

As such, it will NOT include any dynamic changes to the page made by javascript."[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215813/can-new-elements-inserted-with-javascript-be-seen-with-view-source#:~:text=View%20Source%20in%20the%20browser,the%20page%20made%20by%20javascript.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `headers` to get a *proper* `HTML` and not some thrid grade bot wannabe hypertext.

Here's how to get this done:

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.86 YaBrowser/21.3.0.740 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
}


def extract(url):
    res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    the_title = soup.select('meta[name="title"]')[0].attrs['content']
    print('Title: ' + the_title)  # This works fine

    long_text = soup.select('#titleStoryLine .inline.canwrap span')[0].string.strip()
    print('Description: ' + long_text)  # this too works fine

    similar_movies = soup.select('.rec_item img')
    print([i["title"] for i in similar_movies])  # works now :)


extract('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7069210/')
```

Output:

```
Title: The Conjuring 3: The Devil Made Me Do It (2021) - IMDb
Description: A chilling story of terror, murder and unknown evil that shocked even experienced real-life paranormal investigators Ed and Lorraine Warren. One of the most sensational cases from their files, it starts with a fight for the soul of a young boy, then takes them beyond anything they'd ever seen before, to mark the first time in U.S. history that a murder suspect would claim demonic possession as a defense.
['The Conjuring 2', 'The Conjuring 2 Remake', 'The Conjuring', 'The Maiden', 'Conjuring the Devil', 'Billie Eilish: Bury a Friend', 'Oxygen', 'The Curse of La Llorona', 'Annabelle Comes Home', 'Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings', 'Malignant', 'The Nun']
```

Comment: "not some thrid grade bot wannabe hypertext" :D Thanks a lot Sir :). So, the server was stripping some HTML away because it was sensing the request is not from a real browser? Can you direct me to a doc/url where I can learn more about this behavior please? Would be a great help. Thanks again man ...