# How do you test the schema.org metatags of an AngularJS webapp in Google richsnippets testing tool?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, schema.org, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets

The code of the website is being generated with the AngularJS javascript framework. When I visit a webpage it displays the page completely, but the source code is being loaded by parts that are not fully present in the source code, for example:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div ng-include="'partials/header.html'"></div>
        <div id="ng-view" ng-view class="main_view wrapper"></div>
        <!--div ng-include="'partials/home_content.html'"></div-->
        <a href="#"> </a>
    </div>
    <div ng-include="'partials/footer.html'" class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

How do I test partials code (header, content, footer) in https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?

Answer (score 4):

I'm using a software called *prerender* to ensure that crawlers can actually crawl my single page application site in order to index them.

So I just give the testing tool a prerendered page to work on, and I think it's a good idea, because that's exactly how crawlers will get your page anyway.

I'm using prerender, which can be installed on your server or used through their servers (for a price), more info at : https://prerender.io/documentation

Answer (score 1):

Try pasting the generated page source into the "HTML" tab here:

http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Here are a couple of resources to help you get a copy of the generated page source:

- [Best Way to View Generated Source of Webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750865/best-way-to-view-generated-source-of-webpage)
- http://thismightbeuseful.com/website/how-to-view-generated-source-in-chrome-work-around/

---

**UPDATE:**

There's a better, updated HTML testing tool here:

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/structured-data/testing-tool/

[This post](http://www.seoskeptic.com/json-ld-big-day-at-google/) describes it in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a headless browser such as [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) to make google index your angular js web app.

The idea is that if search engine should come across your JavaScript application then you have the permission to redirect the search engine to another URL that serves the fully rendered version of the page.

Check http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.au/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue that you are having.  Once the Google testing tool gets to an "ng-if" it doesn't go forward because it's not going to make that(ng-if) decision.  Unfortunately that's where our structured data lives.

I believe that I may try to have the SD inserted into the DOM back outside and before the ng-if.  Hoping to work on the in the next day or two.  Please let me know if you have found any solutions to working with Angular and Google SD.

Edit:  By the way, I don't think it's just about separating out the code so that it can be tested with the Google testing tool or headerless browser. It's about Google being about to see it when the site is delivered to Google.  If it's still in those same unreachable places then separating it out just for testing doesn't do much good.

Thanks!