# How to make Schema.org work with AngularJS driven page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, schema.org, google-crawlers, google-knowledge-graph

I am using Schema.org for adding my page results in Google’s Knowledge Graph. But my page is controlled by AngularJS and the following is being crawled by Google while testing live data:

```
name:
{{ item.name }}

address:
{{ item.locationName }}

priceRange:
{{ item.displayPrice }}
```

I hoped that crawlers would use data once the page is DOM ready, but it isn't the case. Is there any way to make it work / am I missing something here?

PS: I am open to using something else apart from Schema.org if it works.

Comment: do you have some code that you can post?

Comment: Crawlers, as a rule, do not run JS. They read and then parse and index HTTP response which may contain schema.org markup.  Read http://schema.org/Product rules and Google recomendations https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/search-gallery#events

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but a very related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28027728/2291

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35332430/angularjs-script-tag-json-ld