# Does anyone know a way to print the loaded page HTML after DOM is completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to read the source code of a page after it finished loading and inspect the code to see if it contains a specific text.

I found [this reference](https://webigniter.wordpress.com/2011/05/09/getting-the-html-of-the-current-page-using-javascript/) but this only returns the text visible in the page and not the whole HTML code.

For instance, if the html source code is:

```
<html>
<header>
<header>
<body>
<p> This is a paragraph</a>
<body>
</html>
```

I want the script to print exactly the same thing.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "print"?

Comment: Right click, View Page Source? :)

Comment: What are you looking for in the source code exactly?  Why do you want to "inspect the code" versus using jQuery to traverse the DOM?

Comment: You could take the innerHTML property of the <html> tag, like it is proposed in your link.

Comment: You can get the page markup using document.documentElement.innerHTML (Source:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817218/how-to-get-the-entire-document-html-as-a-string)

Comment: @ShashankReddyKaram good link but based on OP's reference, it seems like he wants the markup from an XMLHttpRequest rather than from the current document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print HTML content on click of a button, but not the page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894683/how-to-print-html-content-on-click-of-a-button-but-not-the-page)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion about the word "print". What I want to achieve is the same result that the "right click > inspect element" would give. 

What I'm trying to do is:
1) Open URL
2) Wait for the page to load
3) Check if page contains an iframe
4) Display a message if the iframe is found

Comment: @LeoS.: Why not just do something like `document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')` (or `$('iframe')`)?  To do this after the page loads, you can use `window.addEventListener('load', function() {})` (or `$(function(){})`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best Way to View Generated Source of Webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750865/best-way-to-view-generated-source-of-webpage)

Answer (score 0):

Do like this, call this function on load

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/yqmxxa53/3/)

```
function printBody() {
  // store oiginal content
  var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

  // get the outer html of the document element
  document.body.innerText = document.documentElement.outerHTML;

  // call window.print if you want it on paper
  window.print();

  // or put it into an iframe
  // var ifr = document.createElement('iframe');
  // ifr.src = 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(document.documentElement.outerHTML);
  // document.body.appendChild(iframe);

  // a small delay is needed so window.print does not get the original
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
  }, 2000);
}
```

Src: [Print <div id=printarea></div> only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only/7532581#7532581)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by 'print' you don't actually mean to transfer it to a paper copy, you can add some script like:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var content = document.documentElement.innerHTML,
        pre = document.createElement('pre'),
        body = document.body;

    pre.innerText = content;

    body.insertBefore(pre, body.firstChild);
});
```

What this does, step by step is:

- `window.addEventListener('load', function()` > Wait for the page to be fully loaded and then execute the function
- `content = document.documentElement.innerHTML` > store the actual page source in the `content` variable (`document.documentElement` refers to the 'root'-node, usually `<html>` in html documents
- `pre = document.createElement('pre')` > create a new `<pre>`-element
- `body = document.body` > create a reference to the `<body>` element
- `pre.innerText = content` > assign the HTML-structure we've stored earlier as text to the `<pre>`-element
- `body.insertBefore(pre, body.firstChild)` > put the `<pre>`-element (now with contents) before any other element in the body (usually on top of the page).

This leaves you with the entire source (as it was before creating the `<pre>`-element containing the source) on top of you page.

---

*Edit: Added `<iframe>` workflow*
It was not clear to me you actually wanted to target an `<iframe>`, so here's how to do that (using a naive approach, more on that further on):

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var iframeList = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe'),
        body = document.body,
        content, pre, i;

    for (i = 0; i < iframeList.length; ++i) {
        content = iframeList[i].documentElement.innerHTML;
        pre = document.createElement('pre');

        pre.innerText = content;
        body.insertBefore(pre, body.firstChild);
    }
});
```

**why is this approach naive?**

There is a thing called [Same-Origin-Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) in javascript, which prevents you from accessing `<iframe>`-content which if the contents do not originate from the same domain as the page containing the `<iframe>`.

There are several ways to take this into consideration, you could wrap the inside of the `for`-loop in `try/catch`-blocks, though I prefer to use a more subtle approach by not even considering `<iframes>` which do not match the Same-Origin-Policy.

In order to do this, you can swap the `getElementsByTagName` method with the [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method (please note the compatibility table at the bottom of that page, see if it matches your requirements).
The `querySelectorAll` accepts a valid CSS selector and will return a `NodeList` containing all matching elements.

A simple selector to use would be
`'iframe[src]:not([src^="//"]):not(src^="http")'` which selects all iframe with a `src` attribute which does *not* start with either `//` or `http`

**Disclaimer**: I *never* use a `<base>`-tag (which changes all relative paths within the HTML) or refer to the current website using a path containing the domain, so the example CSS-selector does not consider these aberrations.

[Can you use `:not()`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)

> IE9 or better

[Can you use `document.querySelector(All)`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector)

> IE8 or better (in order to use with `:not()`, IE9 or better)

*hover/click the boxes above to show the spoiler*

Comment: Hi Rogier, your script works well. I made a small mod to search for the iframe as suggested by @Rocket Hazmat

However, how do I search for another element inside that iframe now?

Currently, my code looks like this:

   ` window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var content =   document.getElementsByTagName('iframe').contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML,
    pre = document.createElement('pre'),
    body = document.body;

    pre.innerText = content;

    body.insertBefore(pre, body.firstChild);
}); `

Comment: You're on the right track, there is just a small mistake: `document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')` will return a `NodeList` containing zero or more elements, it does not return a single element.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over-complicating this problem.  You don't need to "print" the page's HTML or "inspect the code".

In a comment, you said:

> Check if page contains an iframe [and] Display a message if the iframe is found

You can just use DOM traversal functions to examine the DOM.

Try something like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    if(document.getElementsByTagName('iframe').length){
        console.log('Found an iframe');
    }
});
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    if($('iframe').length){
        console.log('Found an iframe');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's so simple, you can use this method to run a script after a page is fully loaded [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

```
function load(){
    console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML);
}
window.onload = load;
```

For further explanations, check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588048/4544056)